# How to use Lagrange interpolation polynomial for functions of multiple variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning, math, interpolation

In the case of interpolating a function of a single variable, things are relatively simple:

```py
def create_basic_polynomial(x_values, i):
    def basic_polynomial(x):
        divider = 1
        result = 1
        for j in range(len(x_values)):
            if j != i:
                result *= (x-x_values[j])
                divider *= (x_values[i]-x_values[j])
        return result/divider
    return basic_polynomial


def create_lagrange_polynomial(x_values, y_values):
    basic_polynomials = []
    for i in range(len(x_values)):
        basic_polynomials.append(create_basic_polynomial(x_values, i))

    def lagrange_polynomial(x):
        result = 0
        for i in range(len(y_values)):
            result += y_values[i]*basic_polynomials[i](x)
        return result
    return lagrange_polynomial


x_values = [0, 2, 3, 5]
y_values = [0, 1, 3, 2]

lag_pol = create_lagrange_polynomial(x_values, y_values)

for x in x_values:
    print("x = {:.4f}\t y = {:4f}".format(x,lag_pol(x)))
```

```bash
x = 0.0000   y = 0.000000
x = 2.0000   y = 1.000000
x = 3.0000   y = 3.000000
x = 5.0000   y = 2.000000
```

But how can we implement the logic for working with functions of multiple variables?

Comment: Exactly the same way as you do with single variables - just with nested loops.

Comment: See <https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3787199/38217>. @lastchance> This is absolutely not the same way...